# React-Router 4, Redirect with dynamic path

Tags: reactjs, react-router

A user receives an email with invitation code like `http://website.com/invitation/%s` where `%s` is an invitation code.

Now I would like to redirect that URL in my app but keep the invitation code like:

```
<Redirect from="/invitation/:code" to="/auth/register/:code" />
```

So when the user clicks the link in email:

`http://website.com/invitation/2abc433`

he will be transferred to:

`http://website.com/auth/register/2abc433`

Unfortunately, with Redirect component like above, he is transferred to

`http://website.com/auth/register/:code`

Comment: Why don't you make the string in our outside the JSX? to={\`/auth/register/${code}\`}

Comment: @DominicTobias I have this `Route` within the `Switch` at the top level of my application. I would probably have to make Component for `/invitation/:code` route and inside make a redirect. While this would work, I was thinking about a simpler solution.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use a stateless component for that :

```
<Route exact path="/invitation/:code" render={props => (
    <Redirect to={`/auth/register/${props.match.params.code}`/>
)}/>
```

`<Redirect>` doesn't support a way to pass parameters directly.

Demo : https://codesandbox.io/s/8kjq4r1m90

Comment: is `exact` having special meaning here?

Comment: Depends on your other routes, of course. For this I guess is an overkill. But if you have `/invitation/accept/some-token` then it will match it as well if it' has no `exact` property.

Comment: I usually put `exact` when my Route has no sub-routes.